# Add an item to ListView (using Tabs)

Tags: android, listview, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm trying to add an item to a ListView which is in one of my 3 tabs, the object will be created on another activity and after creating I want to return to the Tab and there's already shown the object in the ListView, I wanted to do FindViewById in the java class of the Tab but this doesn't work, does anyone know how i could do this?

Code:
Create Idea Activity

```
public class CreateIdeaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_idea);


    final EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ideaTitle);
    final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ideaText);
    final Button create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_create);

    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Idea idea = new Idea(title.getText().toString(),text.getText().toString(),"");
            Manager.AddObjectToIdeaList(idea); // Manager Class: List.add(idea)
        }
        });
}
```

One of my tabs (xml contains ListView) where I want to add items from the Manager-List to the ListView (findViewById does not work):

```
   public class ideastab_main extends Fragment{


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ideastab_main, container, false);
    return rootView;


}
```

}

Comment: Please show us what have you done so far, post your code. From the description you've provided most of us can't give you the solution or the way to find it

Comment: done, I'm sorry :x

Comment: So have you tried rootView.findViewById(...) and there was an error? Have you had the view with the same id in your layout xml as the parameter of the method?

Comment: I didn't know how to do so, now i tried -> EditText text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ideaText); but thats an unreachable statement :(

Comment: The line with `return` should be the last one inside the method. Did you put the line `EditText text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ideaText);` after it?

Comment: oh yea, oh it is working now, thank you :)